# Get the route informations from a Zend_Controller_Request

Tags: php, zend-framework, request, routes

I am trying to get the routing information from a random URL (part of my application).

I tried to instantiate a Zend_Controller_Request_Http with an URL but it didn't fill in the controller, module, action fields automatically.

I suppose it should somehow be linked to the Route info but cannot figure how to connect this.

Any leads?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Its not directly linked. What happens is the router calls its `route` method passing the request as its argument. It then loops through all the registered routes in reverse order calling the route's `match` method with the request as an argument - if it matches it sets the parameters on the request before its returned.

The problem is you cant directly call Zend_Controller_Router_Rewrite::route without modifying the current request cycle, so you have to rely on some "fudgery" or reproduce the logic in this method in your own ruter sbuclass or elsehwere.

**Example of fudging:**

```
// assume $router is your router instance, $request is the REAL request.

$testRequest = new Zend_Controller_Request_Http($url);

// need to use a try because if the route doesnt match youve got an exception coming
try {
  $router->route($testRequest);
} catch(Zend_Controller_Router_Exception $e) {
  $testRequest = false;
}

// revert back to the real current route which was modified during the previous call

$router->route($request);

if(false !== $testRequest) {
  // consume what you need form testRequest as you normally would
  print_r($testRequest->getParams());
}
```

I ran into problems with this down the line after i started getting into more complex request lifecyles. I dont remember why but i do remember my solution was to sub class the router and ad a method that `route` that looked something like this:

```
public function parseRoute(Zend_Controller_Request_Abstract $request)
{

   $preservedRoute = $this->_currentRoute;
   try {

      $router->route($request);
      $this->_currentRoute = $preservedRoute;

   } catch(Zend_Controller_Router_Exception $e) {

      $this->_currentRoute = $preservedRoute;
      return false;
   }

   return $request;
}
```

Also keep in mind this is all from memory and it was with 1.6 or 1.7 not the current version so YMMV. Hope that helps.

Comment: Got the idea, thanks for the tip. As my particular app doesn't have complex routing, I guess I'll fudge my way through.